# Python error 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, random, attributes

So, I have this code:

```
import random, string, os, time
a = 0
random = ''
def calcular():
    global random
    random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in xrange(4)])
    print random
while a<1:
    calcular()
    a=a+1
    pass
print time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
os.system('pause')
```

But I'm getting an

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: you're setting random == a string, and then you're trying to do random.choice.  Your string doesn't have a method of choice.

Comment: Just use a different name for your string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting the module named `random` with a string with the same variable name. Best don't use another name for your string.

```
import random, string, time

def calcular():
    letters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in xrange(4))
    print letters

a = 0
while a<1:
    calcular()
    a += 1
print time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 3):

Both module and string are named `random` and `random = ''` is defined later, so when you do `random.choice` you are trying to call choice method on string object rather than random module.

Solution would be to rename your string to something else.